# TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payments')

Tags: javascript, angular, google-pay

Trying to implement Google Pay and I'm having issues reading that google object returned by this script:

```
<script async src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"></script>
```

[image]

I make a call to log the window, I can see it in the debugger, the object is right there. Then on line 263 I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payments)`

it's confusing me, when I debug in Visual Studio there is never a google object, only when I console.log it and it will show in the debugger. Any help or explanation is appreciated

Comment: console.log is not reliable when printing async variables. try taking out the async keyword in the `<script>` tag and force the browser to download the js file before loading your webpage.  if you want to keep `async`, then you need to utilize the onLoad method as described here https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#js-load

Answer (score 1):

The `google` object is only available at runtime, after the script has executed. You are experiencing a type error. The type checker has no idea what `window.google` is as it doesn't exist before the JS is executed on the browser. Try coercing the type checker like so:`(window as any).google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({ environment: 'TEST' });`